# Should we have Meta posts where people can vote for Development codenames?

Tags: discussion

I was [reading this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames) today, it is where people can suggest code names for upcoming Ubuntu versions.

Do you think we should take part by taking suggestions here?

I am sure the devs would see it and it could be a fun little feature every 6 months or so but would it have any value to the community? We all know Stack Exchange hates fun :)

What do you think?

Here is a [list of Animals and Adjectives](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#A)

Comment: The devs don't decide the codename. Mark Shuttleworth does and he announces it on his blog shortly after the previous release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, we shouldn't**; it won't be of any benefit here.  Besides the 'fun' factor, devs don't make the call on adjectives/naming for the codenames.  (And if we did it for the fun factor, it'd be a "Predict the Name" game, not a "Vote on the codename" thread)

[SABDFL (Self-Appointed Benevolent Dictator For Life)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020/who-is-sabdfl-what-does-he-do) Mark Shuttleworth is the one who decides on the codename, and announces it on his blog shortly after a release is made.

It should also be noted that while that list is a long list of Animals and Adjectives, they're ultimately not voted upon by the community - the actual codename could be one not on the list, so while this may be "fun" it has no actual usefulness beyond the fun factor (as stated above).